# What is the notation for pull-back and push-forward of an exponential map?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

So there is a nice notation for a one-parameter group of transformations $\Phi_t$ corresponding to its infinitesimal generator $\boldsymbol X$:

$$\Phi_t = \exp \left(t \boldsymbol X \right)$$

But what is a common notation then for pull-back ${\Phi_t}^*$ and pushforward ${\Phi_t}_*$ when written via exponent?

Comment: $\exp t \boldsymbol X= \exp (t \boldsymbol X)$?

Comment: @mike yes, sure

Comment: It would have to be $\exp(tX)_*$ and $\exp(tX)^*$ since you did not write the group action explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean written via exponent? What is wrong with the notation you gave?